# не могу создать фон из градиентов

Tags: css, градиент

Всем привет!
Не получается задать фон несколькими градиентами.
Подскажите куда копать?

Фотки с фигмы
`background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(222, 237, 255, 0.6) 0%, rgba(166, 204, 250, 0.5) 100%);`
(http://joxi.ru/bmoKqyeiyRM49m)
`background: linear-gradient(74.55deg, #D1D1D1 22.73%, #CFCFCF 68.66%);`
(http://joxi.ru/D2PnxNkTJ7d5Wr)
`background: linear-gradient(74.55deg, #D3D3D3 22.73%, #F0F0F0 68.66%);`
(http://joxi.ru/krDQ6aWu4R0jZm)
`background: linear-gradient(90deg, #F0F0F0 0%, #D4D4D4 100%);`
(http://joxi.ru/DrlW8xDfy94g5A)

Comment: Добавь в вопрос свою попытку решения (как [repro]), чтобы конкретизировать проблему... а то ее суть пока что не ясна, т.е. непонятно что именно не получается.

Comment: Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, надо нажать текстовую кнопку "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1304018/edit)" под ним. После этого, добавить запускаемый пример можно поставив текстовый курсор в нужное место и нажав сочетание клавиш Ctrl+m (откроется редактор, в котором можно написать разметку и стили. Вставлять в него все-все-все не надо: будет достаточно только той части разметки и стилей, которая наглядно показывает проблему).